# LPTHW: double quotes around CSV.writer

Tags: python

While going through LPTHW, I've set on reading the code here:

https://github.com/BrechtDeMan/secretsanta/blob/master/pairing.py

I've been trying to understand why the output CSV has double-quotes. There are several questions here about the problem but I'm not groking.

Where are the quotes getting introduced?

Edit: I wrote the author a couple of weeks back but haven't heard back.

Edit 2: An example of the output...

```
"Alice,101,alice@mail.org,Wendy,204,wendy@mail.org"
```

Comment: Note that one problem with reading example solutions to Python tutorial materials is that often they're written by people who are also learning.  Nothing wrong with that, but it means that if you follow them too closely you can pick up some nonidiomatic ways to do things.   (The author of that code uses `x.__len__()` instead of `len(x)`; compares integers using `is` where we should use `==`; etc.)

Comment: @DSM I had noticed some of that. Thanks for the caution. It's warranted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes are introduced in `write_file` function.

CSV files look simple on the surface, but sooner or later you will encounter some more complex problems. The first one is: what should happen if character denoting delimiter occurs in field content? Because there is no real standard for CSV format, different people had different ideas of correct answer for this question.

Python `csv` library tries to abstract this complexity and various approaches and make it easier to read and write CSV files following different rules. This is done by [`Dialect` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) objects.

The author of `write_file` function decided to construct output row manually by joining all fields and delimiter characters together, but then used `csv` module to actually write data into file:

```
writer.writerow([givers_list[ind][1] + ',' + givers_list[ind][2]
                + ',' + givers_list[ind][3]
                + ',' + givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][1] + ','
                + givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][2] + ',' + givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][3]])
```

This inconsistent usage of `csv` module resulted in entire row of data being treated as **single field**. Because that field contains characters used as field delimiters, `Dialect.quoting` decides how it should be handled. Default quoting configuration, `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` says that field should be quoted using `Dialect.quotechar` - which defaults to double quote character (`"`). That's why eventually entire field ends up surrounded by double quote characters.

Fast and easy, but not correct, solution would be changing quoting algorithm to `csv.QUOTE_NONE`. This will tell writer object to never surround fields, but instead to escape special characters by `Dialect.escapechar`. According to documentation, setting it to `None` (default) will raise an error. I guess that setting it to empty string could do the job.

The correct solution is feeding `writer.writerrow` with expected input data - list of fields. This should do (untested):

```
writer.writerow([givers_list[ind][1], givers_list[ind][2],
                givers_list[ind][3],
                givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][1],
                givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][2], givers_list[rand_vec[ind]][3]])
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you so much. (And, yes, it works a treat.)

Answer (score 2):

In general, (double)quotes are needed when there is a seperator-char inside a field - and if there are quotes inside that field, they need to be 'escaped' with another quote.

Do you have an example of the output and the quotes you are talking about?

**Edit** (after example):

Ok, the whole row is treated as one field here. As Miroslaw Zalewski mentioned, those values should be treated as seperate fields instead of one long string.

Comment: Ah, I should have included some output. I've added a line above. Each line (or row) has a double-quote on the beginning and end.

Comment: @tcv - ok, the whole row is treated as one field here. As Miroslaw Zalewski mentioned, those values should be treated as seperate fields instead of one long string.